# maven classpath generation for deployment and test

Tags: java, maven-2, classloader

I have a module that is used by creating a custom class loader. The class loader should therefore be created with the path to the module and also all dependencies.

I'm looking for a way to make it productive to work with this mechanism in both dev and production environments.

I thought the build can generate two  files listing all dependency paths. A 'dev' file and 'production' file (then in the code I'd choose the right file based on some system property):

- dev: dependencies should be paths to thirdparty jars in the local maven repository or 'target\classes' for other modules (which will allow to compile with the IDE and not need a full build for each change)
- production: all jars should be copied to a 'lib' folder and the dependencies should list them (without full path). Alternatively, create an uber jar, and then the (?)

So I'm looking for pointers to plugins & pom snippets to help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

- For the dev part, the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its [`dependency:build-classpath`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) can help (and supports writing the output to a file). Another option would be to use the Maven AntRun plugin, it has access to the [Maven runtime classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html), it should be easy to write the property to a file.
- For the prod part, I assume you'll use the Maven Assembly Plugin or the Shade Plugin or another equivalent and I wonder if you couldn't generate a classpath entry in the MANIFEST.MF and rely on it.

Comment: does dependency:build-classpath write the "dev" paths ("target\classes") or only the repo paths? i can instruct the jar plugin to generate manifest.mf, but i think the paths would be to the repo paths

Comment: @IttayD: No, `dependency:build-classpath` doesn't include `target/classes` (why didn't you try?). Regarding the MANIFEST.MF, the classpath entry shouldn't point to the repo path (or your jar wouldn't be portable). Anyway, I've added another (potentially better) suggestion.